# Does mongo log synchronously or asynchronously?

Tags: mongodb, logging

How does mongo log its logs to file?

I could only find that `RotatableFileWriter` uses `std::ofstream`.

Can mongo block while writing to its log if disk slows down, hangs somehow or remote file system is unavailable?

Thanks,

Michal

Answer (score 0):

Synchronous/Asynchronous - It can be configured.

```
The default in the wiredtiger_open call for transaction_sync 
is enabled=false, method=fsync. When the setting is enabled=false the 
log writes should not be synchronous until someone uses a transaction 
with sync=true. 

More info: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/WT-1949

Info on Mongdb logging:
http://blog.mongodb.org/post/172254834/mongodb-is-fantastic-for-logging
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-log-data/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/
```

Comment: I think it's not what I'm asking about. I'm not interested in using mongo as service/storage for logs of my application. I would like to know if mongo, when it logs its own log messages to file, does it in asynchronous manner.